# Error with VB.NET/SQL Server Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

**Background**: I have a Windows form in Visual Studio 2010 with VB.NET code.  On the form I have a combo box where I can select a record from my SQL table. When a selection is made, several text boxes are then filled with my SQL table data.

**Problem**: I need to edit the information that is dumped into those text boxes.  By edit, I mean I need to change the contents of the text boxes on the Windows form, Click my Update button, and the contents of my SQL table be Updated.

**Here is my code:**

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim conDim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=fakeservername; Database=fakedatabasename; integrated security=true"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Users " & _
                           "SET User_FName = '" & Trim(txtFName.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_LName = '" & Trim(txtLName.Text) & "' ," & _
                           "User_Address = '" & Trim(txtAddress.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_City = '" & Trim(txtCity.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_State = '" & Trim(txtState.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_Zip = '" & Trim(txtZip.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_Phone = '" & Trim(txtPhone.Text) & "'," & _
                           "User_AltPhone = '" & Trim(txtAltPhone.Text) & "'," & _
                           "WHERE Users.User_ID ='" & (txtUserID.Text) & "';")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

**Here is my error:**

"*Incorrect syntax near the word 'Where'.*"

I've looked all over the internet for the answer to this question.  I think I'm tip-toeing around the answer but I just can't put my finger on it.  So, I'm coming to you all.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: *`Server=fakeservername; Database=fakedatabasename; integrated security=true`* [I think you should have set `integrated security=fake`, since there's no security integrated into what you're doing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is additional comma in the last column before `where` condition that is not required.

```
"User_AltPhone = '" & Trim(txtAltPhone.Text) & "',"
```

should be

```
"User_AltPhone = '" & Trim(txtAltPhone.Text) & "'"
```

Comment: You da man!  Funny how such a small thing can ruin everything!  It's working perfectly now.  Thanks!

Comment: @AaronHurst Does it work if the user's last name is O'Reilly?